# PHP / MySQL Adjacency List Question

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, adjacency-list

I have the following issue : imaging an adjacency list, that's been walked over with a recursion 
coming out of a sql like this

```
SELECT * FROM pages as ps  ORDER BY COALESCE(child_of,page_id), page_id LIMIT x,y

 public static function tree(&$arr, $id = NULL) {

    $result = array();

    foreach ($arr as $a) {

        if ($id == $a['child_of']) {

            $a ['children'] = self::tree($arr, $a['page_id']);

            $result[] = $a;
        }

    }

    return $result;
}
```

So far, so good - with another "flattener" I am getting where I need to be. Now , here is the trick , 
this works on "paginated" results, and what possibly can happen ( and it does ) is that the parent can be in one subset and the child in a different subset. With the recursion above is obvious that 
the child won't make it to the tree with a missing parent.

Any ideas on how can i solve that? 
Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchical data in relational tables, don't we all love it?

With your current database layout, you can only solve your problem by either always fetching all nodes, or doing as many `JOINS` as you have nesting levels, sort everything properly (your way of sorting only makes this fundamental problem, that you have, a little less important).

Before you ask, **No**, you should **not** do this.

The other method you have, is choose an entirely different model to create your hierarchy:

- Nested sets
- ascendant/descendant relationships between *all* nodes.

See slide 48 et seq. [here](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back).

Comment: well, it's not like i don't understand the complications of left joins, nor do i agree with that solution, especially on unkown depth i don't even think it's a solution at all. To be quite honest oracle already does that, so by now one would expect mysql would've grown enough as well. I don't like the nested sets either. There are 2 things i can do - rethink the way with path depth column , or just put the set limitation on the result not the DB call.

Comment: @gentec: I agree about the first part :) However, I don't understand the second part. Simply adding a depth column will not help you fix your problem! The second you mentioned, I do not understand. What about the second point I suggested? This is what I used when I needed to store trees. -- Btw: Nested sets work very well if you want to do just that, and they work for not-so-very-large trees reasonably well, too. Also, there are implementations for this in ORMs, all I've seen yet use the nested sets approach, but maybe that has changed since I last looked into it.

Comment: sorry , i wasn't clear. i am looking at page 55 of the presentation. this was another idea i had but i dumped it.i am talking about storing pseudo-paths.

Comment: @gentec: I wouldn't use that if I were you. Have a look at page 68!

Comment: Interesting, though i am not sure maintaining a reference table is very maintainable. Imagine for a second you loose it - relations are gone for good, having the information in the same table makes me feel more fuzzy ;) Nevertheless , very good presentation. If it's yours - my greatest regards:)

Comment: @gentec: I'm not sure whether "making you feel more fuzzy" is good or bad, but imagine this for a second: losing your nodes table => your data is gone for good. I'm not sure what kind of argument "losing your relationships-table" is, but it's not a common use-case :) No, it's not my presentation hehe  -- With that model, it's easier to maintain your hierarchy, I think, also, when you insert one node, you would have to update **all** nodes with the nested sets model.

Comment: "feeling warm and fuzzy" is just a figure of speech and it means that makes one feel good about something. I agree it might not be quite an argument - but it's possible. I will run tests tomorrow and I will report. Thank you so much for your pointers. I am going to mark your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A good read to start with is [Hierarchical Data In MySQL](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/database-design/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql) *(which I used to be able to find on the MySQL.com website, arghh)*

Read It?

Here's how it could be done with the adjacency list model. But **only for a known fixed amount of nesting** *(four nesting levels for this example)*.

I would find out which of my pages are root pages *(of the tree)*. Then select only those with a query. Put the `LIMIT x,x` in this select statement.

After that, the following statement: *(or something like it)*

```
string query = "
    SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
    FROM category AS t1
    LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
    LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
    LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
    WHERE t1.name IN('ELECTRONICS', '<some other name>');
";
```

Could return something like this:

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
| lev1        | lev2                 | lev3         | lev4  |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | TUBE         | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | LCD          | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | PLASMA       | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | MP3 PLAYERS  | FLASH |
| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | CD PLAYERS   | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | 2 WAY RADIOS | NULL  |
| etc...      | etc...               | etc...       |       |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
```

The trick is to use only the root names of the query with limit *(or ID's if you want)* in the `IN()` statement of the query.

This should perform pretty good still *(in theory)*.

The principle of the above query could also be used to find out how many descendants are in a root of a tree *(with a little `GROUP BY`and `COUNT()` magic ;)* Also, you could find out which of your pages are roots with this principle *(though I would save that in the tabledata for performance reasons)*

If you want a **dynamic amount of nesting** *(for nearly endless scaling)*, implementing a [nested set](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/database-design/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql) would be the way to go.